# How to programmatically set the current page for UIPageControl?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have 3 "pages" (page 0, page 1, page 2) in a UIScrollView that are snapped to by finger swipes. There is a UIPageControl there too. The UIScrollView starts off presenting page 0. What I want to do is present page 3 FIRST sometimes. How can I do this programmatically.

Simply setting currentPage (of UIPageControl) to the page number does nothing by the way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(From the PageControl example)

To go directly to a particular section of the scrollView use

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

---

I just implemented the same,  e.g scrollview and page control and used the

```
pageControl.currentPage = {pageNumber};
```

which worked perfectly, are you sure that the pageControl outlet is set correctly in Interface Builder (if you're using it).

If the problem is that the scrollView is not working, and not the pageControl. Then make sure that you have the contentsize of the scrollView set correctly.

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*numberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

To this scrollview you then add the content to each section

```
page1ViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
[scrollView addSubview:page1ViewController.view];
```

Next page gets pushed over 1 screen width

```
page2ViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 200);
[scrollView addSubview:page2ViewController.view];
```

Comment: What exactly should be connected to what? my UIPageControl is connected to my RootViewController directly and not my ScrollViewController (All in the Same xib file)

Comment: Create Outlets in your controller for both the scrollView and pageControl


@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;


@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

and link these to the controls in the xib